# SharedPreferences MODE_PRIVATE security

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreferences to store my keys and my crypted messages.If i store them crypted in it and then decrypt in my app it takes some time, but i am confused about if it will secure to store them decrpyted in SharedPreferences.
Can anybody reach my SharedPreferences MODE_PRIVATE with special app or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a rooted phone, yes, it can access the shared preferences for your app. Also, on any phone the user can delete all the data that it's stored in shared preferences by clearing the cache in the application manager.
A safe way to store data would be to encrypted it with AES and save it in a text file in the root folder of your app.